# Issues with comma separated data  with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Am Trying  to convert an XML data into CSV with XSLT. The rows are separated with commas but  some of the data have double quotes.  i used the following codes for the conversion but it doesn't handle the data properly, especially the rows with quotes.

this is my sample data

```
<Add>
<Rowinfo>
<LocatorD>Dwelling  </LocatorD>
<LName> shark </LName>
<L>1</L>
<AArea>Abesinia Passage</AArea>
</Rowinfo>
```

when the XSL is applied to the above data it produces

```
LocatorDesignator,LocatorName,     Locator      ,  Thoroughfare     ,      AddressArea

Dwelling         ,     shark ,       1          ,   Abesinia Passage,

Shop 01-Feb,Shop ,       1   , Casenapes Square ,                   ,
```

But the intended result is to produce

```
LocatorDesignator,LocatorName,Locator,   Thoroughfare      ,       AddressArea

Dwelling         ,     shark ,  1    ,   Abesinia Passage  ,

Shop 01-Feb      ,     Shop  ,  1    ,    Casenapes Square ,
```

In other words when you open this as a CSV file

- Shop 01-Feb,Shop  happend to be in a single column
- instead of seperate columns such as:

  LocatorDesignator| LocatorName

  Shop 01-Feb,shop|

instead of

```
LocatorDesignator| LocatorName
Shop 01-Feb      | Shop
```

Comment: You need to be much more specific: 1) what is your input document, 2) what is your expected output, 3) what is your actual output and what did you do to get it. Use [short, self-contained, compileable examples](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Is XSLT really the right solution for this task? Most programming languages have XML reading capabilities and CSV writing capabilities. I'd have thought it could be written as a fairly short concise script in any language you wanted to use.

Comment: Please forgive me my ignorance but what's the difference between the actual and expected output? Just whitespace?

Comment: Are the spaces between the values and the commas significant? If not there is no difference between your expected output and your actual output! If so, there is no way you got output you say you did because you have no code to insert all those space characters. Please clarify.

Comment: And why do you have input value "shop starting with a double-quote, but this double-quote does not appear in the output? Is it a typo?

Comment: Also, your second row has an element (Thoroughfare) not present in the first row. Is this an error? or legitimate data?

Comment: @ Sean B.Durkin i Added the spaces so that it cant be distinctly seperated. the "shop came with the data and i should think that is the course of the problem. if it could some how handle both commas and double quoutes, i think that should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Rowinfo[1]/*" mode="heading" />
   <xsl:value-of select="'&#x0A;'" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="*/Rowinfo" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rowinfo/*" mode="heading" >
 <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
 <xsl:if test="position() != last()">  
  <xsl:value-of select="','" />
 </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rowinfo">
  <xsl:variable name="line-with-extra-comma">
   <xsl:for-each select="*">
    <xsl:variable name="col-name" select="local-name()" />
    <xsl:if test="../../Rowinfo[1]/*[local-name() = $col-name]">
      <xsl:call-template name="csv-encode" />
      <xsl:value-of select="','" />
    </xsl:if>  
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable> 
 <xsl:value-of select="concat(
      substring($line-with-extra-comma, 1,
      string-length($line-with-extra-comma) - 1),
    '&#x0A;')" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="escape-value">
 <xsl:param name="text" />
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&quot;')">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat( substring-before($text,'&quot;'), '&quot;&quot;')" />
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-value">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,'&quot;')" />
    </xsl:call-template>  
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:value-of select="$text" /> 
  </xsl:otherwise>  
 </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="csv-encode">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="contains(.,',') or starts-with(.,'&quot;')">
   <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'" />
    <xsl:call-template name="escape-value">
     <xsl:with-param name="text" select="text()" /> 
    </xsl:call-template>  
   <xsl:value-of select="'&quot;'" /> 
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
  </xsl:otherwise>  
 </xsl:choose>  
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...will take this input document...

```
<Address>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>Dwelling  </LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName> shark </LocatorName>
        <Locator>1</Locator>
        <AddressArea>Abesinia Passage</AddressArea>
    </Rowinfo>
    <Rowinfo>
        <LocatorDesignator>"Shop 01-Feb</LocatorDesignator>
        <LocatorName>"Shop</LocatorName>
        <Locator>1</Locator>
        <Thoroughfare>Casenapes Square</Thoroughfare>
        <AddressArea/>
    </Rowinfo>
</Address>
```

...and transform it into this csv output...

```
LocatorDesignator,LocatorName,Locator,AddressArea
Dwelling  , shark ,1,Abesinia Passage
"""Shop 01-Feb","""Shop",1,
```

### Caveats

I have assumed that:

1. Column headings are defined by the child elements of the first row. If it is possible for table to be empty (no rows), you will need to adjust accordingly.
2. Elements by name appear in the same order in subsequent rows as they do in the first row.
3. Subsequent rows may contain extraneous child elements, but never missing ones. Extraneous elements are dropped.
4. Csv output is proper csv output. Values are double-quote escaped if either they contain a comma or start with a double-quote.
5. All values are single-line. Multi-line csv is not handled by this script.
6. The output line terminator is LF. If you need CR.LF or something else, adjust accordingly.

Comment: @ Sean B Enough RESPECT!     however i would extremly need your expertise at " manipulation of XML textnode with xslt". Thank you

Comment: Ok. I will take a look at it.

Comment: @lee, as others have commented, there is way not enough explanation of the required rules of transformation for your other question. Please update it.

Comment: @ Sean B.Durkin if you look at it this way, in an xml document, you want to delete some unwanted values from each text node.this values you intend to delete happens to be PART of the text node. for example you have "MR LEE" and u want to delete "LEE" to have "MR"

Comment: The problem is that you have not articulated any rules to say **which** part.

Comment: if we start with the locator name the part in double quotes are to be deleteed : (row1) "Flat  -" Buena Villa House.   (row2) "Flat  3a"  Anderson's House .(row3) "office Unit 2a"   Funlife Building

Comment: Update your question accordingly.

Comment: Sean B this is the last task of this project and i have almost killed myself on it considering am a newbee. you could be my God sent Angel in this.