# Transformer Error

Tags: java, xml, csv

I have An object that does a simple transformation. i have created a style sheet that transforms XML data to CSV. After the transformation, a CSV file is created but with empty content.

```
public class Simplex
 {

private String xmlFile ;
private String xslFile;
private String  outputFile;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Simple
 */
   public Simplex(String xmlFile, String xslFile,String outputFile)
  {
   this.xmlFile = xmlFile;
    this.xslFile = xslFile;
   this.outputFile= outputFile;
  }

 public String simplexTransform() throws    
TransformerException,TransformerConfigurationException,FileNotFoundException,
IOException

  {String mystring = "";

  TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslFile));
 transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlFile), new StreamResult(new    
FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
  return mystring = "*Data Has Been Transformed,Check ouput File *";
  } 
}
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here for me to help you. What are the values of `xmlFile` and `xslFile`? If they are not URIs, then that is your problem. If they are, then what are the contents of the files that they point to?

Comment: these are my inputs C:\\thefiles\\Abbey.xml

C:\\thefiles\\Abbeybe.csv 

c:\\thefiles\\ABBEY\\CSVcon8.xsl

Comment: Ok, good, so at least you are using the StreamSource constructor correctly (I've made that mistake plenty of times). What are the contents (or at least the structures) of Abbey.xml and CSVcon8.xsl?

Comment: how do i explain that. the xml has for elements on each row and the CSVcon8.xsl simply converts the XML to CSV.

Comment: My current theory is that your XSL may not be set up properly to work with your XML file. If you are 100% confident that both your XML and your XSL files are correct, then I may not be able to help you.

Comment: Where transformer takes SSL and transform to XSL use your XML to the factory defaults.

Comment: @ Cody, if you go to this link, you would find the exact XSL used for converting xml to csv http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124674/issues-with-comma-separated-data-with-xslt  then you can save in a file and pass as inputs to the method. the thing is sometimes it does create csv file but sometimes it doesnt. or i'll rather go for a java method that converts xml data to csv and handles all double quote inconsistencies. if you can help with that.